# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'btn' is undefined

Tags: python, jinja2

I am getting jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'btn' is undefined exception while logging to the localhost. The btn is properly defined but still.. Can I plaese get the help as soon as possible. Thank You in Advance
Python code- This code is the Python Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from send_email import send_email
from sqlalchemy.sql import  func
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/success", methods=['POST'])
def success():
    global file
    if request.method=='POST':
        file=request.files["file"]
        file.save(secure_filename("uploaded" + file.filename))
        with open("uploaded"+file.filename,"a") as f :
            f.write("This was added later!")
        return render_template("index.html", btn="download.html")

@app.route("/download")
def download():
    return send_file("uploaded" + file.filename, attatchment_filename="yourfile.csv", as_attatchment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

HTML-
Index file - This is the main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title> Data Collector App</title>
    <head>
        <link href="../static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Collecting Height</h1>
            <h3>Please Fill the Entries to get Population Statistics on Height</h3>
            <div class="message">
                {{text | safe}}
            </div>
            <form action="{{url_for('success')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" > <br>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {%include btn ignore missing%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Download file- This is the html file for downloading. After importing the file this html code will create a button in the same index.html page  so that I can also downoad the same file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <div class="download">
            <a href= {{url_for('download')}} target="blank"> <button class="btn"> Download </button></a>
        </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: `def index(): return render_template("index.html")` <- that's the same template and I dont see `btn` defined anywhere

Comment: required btn template {%include btn ignore missing%}

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue. My workaround was to replace:

```html
{% include btn ignore missing %}
```

with

```html
{% if btn %}
     {% include btn %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`{% include [btn] ignore missing %}`

The reason for change is due to a Flask update from the time when that video was created